# Vala - How to join string[] to string?

Tags: arrays, string, vala

I have a string array:

```cs
string[] arr = {"Hello", "World"};
```

I want to print it or convert it to a string like:

```cs
print(arr.join(","));

> "Hello,World"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string.joinv()](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/string.joinv.html):

```cs
string[] arr = {"Hello", "World"};

print(string.joinv(",", arr));
```

Result:

```
Hello,World
```